# markitup preview toggle

Tags: markitup

I want to add a button to a markitup set by which i can toggle preview, that is if i click on preview button i can see the preview, if i want to hide the preview - i can hide it by using that button. I've googleed for this but still no result. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i've figured it out. I've added a button to hide it, code as below -

```
{name:'Hide Preview', call: function (markitUp){ miu.hidepreview()}, className:'hidepreview'}
```

Where hidepreview() as my custom function. I defined this function as below

```
miu = {
hidepreview : function(){
    $('.markItUpPreviewFrame').remove();
}
```

}

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by holding the Alt key and clicking on the Preview button - this will close the opened preview window.

It's in the **else if** statement of the preview() function:

```
} else if (altKey === true) {
    if (iFrame) {
        iFrame.remove();
    } else {
        previewWindow.close();
    }
    previewWindow = iFrame = false;
}
```